# Find entry that causes low p-value

Tags: r, statistics, table-statistics

In R is have 2 vectors

```
u <- c(109, 77, 57, 158, 60, 63, 42, 20, 139, 15, 64, 18)
v <- c(734, 645, 1001, 1117, 1071, 687, 162, 84, 626, 64, 218, 79)
```

I want to test H: `u` and `v` are independent so I run a chi-square test:

```
chisq.test( as.data.frame( rbind(u,v) )  )
```

and get a very low p-value meaning that I can reject H, meaning that `u` and `v` are not independent.

But when I type

```
chisq.test(u,v)
```

I get a p-value on 0.23 which mean that I can accept H.
Which one of these two test should I chose ?

Furthermore I want to find the entries in these vectors that causes this low p-value. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Obviously the second is correct `chisq.test(u,v)`. If you provide just a data.frame a goodness-of-fit test is performed and the df is treated as a contingency table. Check `?chisq.test`.

Comment: Hum, 121 df seems like a big price to pay for checking distribution of 2x12 numbers. Perhaps `chisq.test(u, p = v, rescale.p = TRUE)`? What do you think, @LyzandeR?

Comment: Hi @RomanLuštrik . I definitely agree that 121 degrees of freedom is a big price to pay when checking the independence of two very small vectors. Now, if you do `chisq.test(u, p = v, rescale.p = TRUE)` aren't you essentially performing a goodness of fit test which is a bit different to testing the independence? This seems to support [this](http://ww2.coastal.edu/kingw/statistics/R-tutorials/goodness.html) but I might be wrong.

Comment: @LyzandeR feel free to visit R(-public) where we can chat about it.

Comment: Which test should I use then ?

Answer (score 0):

The test statistic uses the sum of squared standardised residuals. You can look at these values to get an idea of the importance of particular values

```
m = chisq.test(u, v)

residuals(m)
m$stdres
```

Comment: So residuals with a high absolut value shoud be considered and how should one decide this?